# GPU is not used in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, gpu, device-manager

**My system:**

My OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363

My GPU: AMD Radeon HD 5800 Series. Driver date 04.11.2015

My CPU (just in case this is relevant): Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 750 @ 2.67GHz, 2661 MHz, 4 Core(s), 4 logical processor(s)

**My problem:**

My computer does not seem to use the GPU.

- In the Performance tab of Task Manager, the GPU does not show up.
- In the Processes tab of Task Manager, I can set it to show GPU and GPU-module, however, the column GPU-module is empty and the GPU always stays at 0%, even when playing games like Prey for example. If I close Task Manager and open it again, GPU and GPU-module disappear again.
- In Device Manager, however, my graphics card is listed.
- EDIT: I realized the problem today, but am not able to specify when it began occurring.

**What I've tried:**

- Checked for new Windows updates > None are found.
- Checked for new drivers in Device Manager > None are found.
- Checked for updates in the AMD Catalyst Control Center > None are found.
- Attempted to download the most recent driver from [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support) > Unable to find my GPU in the list.
- Attempted to automatically download the most recent driver with the tool recommended on the AMD site > [Error 182](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-kb182): Radeon Software was not able to recognize AMD graphics hardware

**My question:**

How do I get Windows 10 to recognize my GPU?

*To avoid closure: My question is different from several similar questions since I am not even able to find the most recent driver for my GPU; therefore, I cannot just uninstall/reinstall them.*

Comment: I can see "ATI Radeon HD 5830",  "ATI Radeon HD 5850", and  "ATI Radeon HD 5870" in that list. Pick one of them. Yours says "Series" which would include any of those devices. ATI device names are slightly generic.

Comment: You have only two choices for that card series 15.7.1 or 16.2.1 beta. Try the 15 first, ignore the beta unless the 15 doesn't work. https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/ati-radeon-hd-5000-series/ati-radeon-hd-5850 These cards were abandoned 4 years ago, though they still kind of work in win10 there will come a time they won't.

Comment: Your CPU does not contain a GPU, hence if your monitor already uses your graphics card. And as the card is a bit old I am not sure if installing the old AMD drivers is a good idea. I would try to remove all AMD drivers and use the drivers provided by Microsoft.

Comment: @Robert - good observation on the CPU chipset not having onboard graphics… but specifically for this card series the 15.7.1 is **the** go-to driver revision, for many reasons. Windows *might* come up with the same, but might not. The 'might not' is probably why it's misbehaving at the moment. This driver revision crops up a lot on an online support structure I work with.

Comment: @Robert Does that mean that my computer already correctly uses the GPU and the 0% from the Task Manager are wrong?
I now installed the AMD Catalyst drivers. Both, the 15.7.1 and the 16.2.1 beta version do not change the situation, (also after restarting the computer).

Comment: Did you use the 'advanced' install option & force it to clean install? Did you check it's now using the correct driver set?

Comment: When using the 15.7.1 and 16.2.1 beta downloads, I am not able to choose a _clean install_ option. When I just do the regular installation and then go to the "new" Catalyst Center (now just called "Radeon Settings") and try to update there, then the graphical interface looks like the one on YouTube if I search for "clean install AMD". It also finds some updates. However, when choosing them, I get the Error 175 (https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-kb175), which again tells me to download  15.7.1 or the Cimson Edition (which also does not give me a _clean installation_ option).

Comment: The driver version stays at 15.301.1901.0 after all of the different installations.

Comment: 15.301.1901.0 is the 16.2.1 beta, so we can't tell what happened earlier. The installer has a Custom button part way through the install. Use it.